# Cannot add KeyVault Secret-scoped role assignment with Azure Bicep

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I am deploying something in the `dev` ressource group. Something in it has a dependency on a key-vault secret which is stored in a different ressource group `main`. From the main.bicep I am calling a **role-assignment-secret.bicep** module to deploy the role assignment:

```
param role string
param assignee string
param vaultName string
param secretName string

resource secret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-11-01-preview' existing = {
  name: '${vaultName}/${secretName}'
  scope: resourceGroup('main')
}

resource perm 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(vaultName, secretName, assignee, role)
  properties: {
    principalId: assignee
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', role)
  }
  scope: secret
}
```

Now `secret` yields an error, stating that:

```
A resource's scope must match the scope of the Bicep file for it to be deployable. You must use modules to deploy resources to a different scope.bicep(BCP139)
```

Than I re-factored the module to include another module

ADD **role-assignment.bicep**

```
param role string
param assignee string

resource perm 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(deployment().name, assignee, role)
  properties: {
    principalId: assignee
    roleDefinitionId: subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', role)
  }
}
```

Which is then called by **role-assignment-secret.bicep**

```
param role string
param assignee string
param vaultName string
param secretName string

resource secret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2021-11-01-preview' existing = {
  name: '${vaultName}/${secretName}'
  scope: resourceGroup('main')
}

module perm 'role-assignment.bicep' = {
  name: guid(vaultName, secretName, assignee, role)
  scope: secret
  params: {
    assignee: assignee
    role: role
  }
}
```

This then yields the follwing error

```
Scope "resource" is not valid for this module. Permitted scopes: "resourceGroup".bicep(BCP134)
```

So basically Bicep is telling me that I cannot assign the role jsut for that specific secret, right? But I need to do this, I can easily do so via the portal GUI. Using a resource group as scope for the role assignment is to broad and results in excessive permissions being granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, there was an obvious oversight on my part. Instead of explicitly providing the scope property WITHIN the role-assignment-secret.bicep template, I should have injected it from outside when calling the module from the main.bicep. Working now. Apologies.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your final solution?